# How to compare two JSON responses in groovy and get the differences (similar to what json editor does)?

Tags: json, groovy, assert

Can someone please tell me why the error happens and possible alternatives in solving this

My code:

```
def actual = " [{"inputs":[{"__typename":"ElementalField"}],"constraint":"FILE-STATUS:REPORT-STATUS:REPORT-STATUS-1='0'","source":{"sourceCodeFiles":[{"fileName":"/usr/src/workspace/PC/source/cobol/PCCTRE.cob","sourceLines":[{"nodes":[{"id":"8326"}],"lineNumber":620}]}],"__typename":"Source"},"branchExecuted":false},{"inputs":[{"__typename":"ElementalField"}],"constraint":"FILE-STATUS:TRAND-STATUS:TRAND-STATUS-1='0'","source":{"sourceCodeFiles":[{"fileName":"/usr/src/workspace/PC/source/cobol/PCCTRE.cob","sourceLines":[{"nodes":[{"id":"8369"}],"lineNumber":634}]}],"__typename":"Source"},"branchExecuted":false}]"

def expected =  "[{"inputs":[{"__typename":"ElementalField"}],"constraint":"FILE-STATUS:REPORT-STATUS:REPORT-STATUS-1='0'","source":{"sourceCodeFiles":[{"fileName":"/usr/src/workspace/PC/source/cobol/PCCTRE.cob","sourceLines":[{"nodes":[{"id":"8326"}],"lineNumber":620}]}],"__typename":"Source"},"branchExecuted":false},{"inputs":[{"__typename":"ElementalField"}],"constraint":"FILE-STATUS:TRAND-STATUS:TRAND-STATUS-1='0'","source":{"sourceCodeFiles":[{"fileName":"/usr/src/workspace/PC/source/cobol/PCCTRE.cob","sourceLines":[{"nodes":[{"id":"8366"}],"lineNumber":634}]}],"__typename":"Source"},"branchExecuted":false}]"

def removedA = actual.replaceAll("[_]","").trim();
def removedE = expected.replaceAll("[_]","").trim();

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(removedA)

//Checks all elements of resource one by one and compare with expectedData
json.each{k, v -> assert v == removedE."$k" }
```

Here is the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script23$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.groovy.json.internal.LazyMap) values: [[inputs:[[typename:ElementalField]], constraint:FILE-STATUS:REPORT-STATUS:REPORT-STATUS-1='0', ...]] Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll(), findAll(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object) error at line: 37
```

Comment: This is invalid groovy code (the strings containing the JSON are not properly quoted).

Comment: Can you please provide example of the valid one using my response?

Comment: Try single quotes?

Comment: I removed surrounding double quote :
def removedA = actual.replaceAll("[_]","").trim();                    
so the output is [{"inputs":[{"typename":"ElementalField"}],"constraint":"FILE-........}]                   but still getting the same error

Comment: also I used single quote [{'inputs':[{'typename':'ElementalField'}...] but https://csvjson.com/ gives invalid JSON error

Comment: Please update the question with what you have tried and the presumable
fixed string.